# How to install vim on Cygwin

Tags: windows, vim, makefile, cygwin

First, I saw that you can install vim normally in the setup.exe, but I realized that I wanted to install vim with Ruby support. I downloaded the vim 7.3, untared it and ran

```
./config --enable-ruby-interp
```

and everything configured fine. Then I ran

```
$ make && make install
```

and everything installed ok, but it put a `vim.exe` in `/usr/local/bin`. I don't want a `vim.exe`, I want a `vim`, which I can run by typing

```
$ vim
```

in my Cygwin shell.

Is there a way to tell vim during the installation to install it like it would if I was on Linux? Meaning, to ignore the fact that I'm on Windows?

Now, when I type `vim` into the shell, it just does nothing. So it found it, but it doesn't do anything with it.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but the last time I used cygwin all commands could be seen as `.exe` files from the explorer. the cygwin shell is smart enough to add the extension when you type `vim` afaik.

Comment: I think you're right, because when I type `which vim`, it shows me `/usr/local/bin/vim`, and in `/usr/local/bin` there is only `vim.exe`. But the reason I began inspecting that was that, when I type `vim`, nothing happens.

Comment: Why would you prefer Cygwin vim to native one (which comes with Ruby support compiled in)?

Comment: There is a native one? In the Cygwin setup you can choose to install vim that comes with it. That vim doesn't have Ruby support. So I chose not to install that one, but rather to download the vim package from the Internet and compile it myself. And then this problem happens when I try to run it (that it doesn't do anything when I type `vim` into the shell).

Comment: @janko-m [This](http://users.skynet.be/antoine.mechelynck/vim/compile.htm) may be of some help. If not, it looks like strace is your friend. The dump should tell you what's going on when your program gets launched

Comment: What exactly happens, if you type `/usr/local/bin/vim.exe`? Do you get an error message, does it hang, or do you just get a new command prompt? And, when you installed it from the internet, did you make sure to compile it with the Cygwin C++ compiler?

Comment: Did you install the cygwin package [vim-ruby](https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/vim-ruby.html)? What kind of Ruby support is still missing after installing it?

Answer (score 0):

You can drop a Windows build of Vim that has Ruby support (like [this one](https://bintray.com/micbou/generic/vim)) into your PATH (add vim's folder to PATH before everything else) and then when you run `vim` from inside cygwin it will run that (the first vim.exe in PATH. should also work in cygwin's MinTTY)

Remember to close and re-open your shell after changing PATH from windows settings.

Comment: Maybe it's worth pointing out, that a Windows build Vim probably can't handle Cygqin path names, so it might be advisable to define a conver function which converts pathes on the commandline to either mixed- or Windows format. I had to do the same when I installed the Metapad text editor for use in Cygwin.

Answer (score -1):

reinstall the cygwin, or re-install git-bash. (which also included the cygwin environment)

Comment: In what way should help this the OPs problem? I don't see that his cygwin installation would be broken ....

Comment: by default, the vim is bundled with cygwin, which means that： once you have installed the cygwin successfully on windows, you will able to run "vim" command without install vim. so I suggest him to `reinstall` cygwin.

Comment: If the vim installation is broken, it would suffice to only install the package containing vim, not all of cygwin. However, the OP explicitly noted that he does **not** want the default installation which comes with cygwin, but do his own configuration. Reinstalling would not help here.

Comment: Cygwin is a very wired product ( simulate a linux vim software in windows), I don't really don't care what the answer is. You are correct. But I would prefer to use Linux instead of Cygwin.